# Path created by a line wrapping a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, curves

I have a circle and a line with the length of its circumference. One end of the line is attached to a point on the circle circumference, forming the shape of the lowercase 'b'.
Now, the line begins to wrap the circle clockwise, until it completes one revolution around the circle, where there's no more "line".

What is the path created by the free end of the line?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involute#Involutes_of_a_circle

Comment: It's the [involute of the circle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involute#Involutes_of_a_circle), similar but not identical to an Archimedean spiral.

Comment: Do you mean the parameterization of the path?

Comment: @AnneBauval Involute is what I was looking for, please post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name you are looking for is [involute of a circle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involute#Involutes_of_a_circle).